# Text In-screen Implementation in java-libGDX

Tags: java, android, fonts, libgdx

I have some trouble with implementing a feature to show and use the player's username. I'm making a crossplatform app between windows and android where I'm trying to showcase the player's name as soon as they start typing and can press enter to proceed or press the ***Level Selection***-button to proceed to the next screen. Every time I press **''Enter''** though, it crashes. Also, doesn't it display or take in the player's name. I know the code is not optimal as I made multiple tables for example but I was hoping somebody could tell me where I made my mistake so it would maybe work. Thanks in advance!

This is the code:

```
package com.paladinzzz.game.screens;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Input;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Screen;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureRegion;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.InputEvent;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.ImageButton;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Table;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.TextButton;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.utils.ClickListener;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.utils.Drawable;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.utils.TextureRegionDrawable;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.viewport.FillViewport;
import com.paladinzzz.game.CrossplatformApp;
import com.paladinzzz.game.util.Constants;
import com.paladinzzz.game.audio.MusicHandler;
import static com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx.input;
import static com.paladinzzz.game.screens.MenuScreen.musicHandler;


public class LoginScreen implements Screen {

private CrossplatformApp game;
private Stage stage;
private ImageButton backButton, playButton;
private Texture backTexture, playTexture, background;
private Drawable drawableBack, drawablePlay;
private OrthographicCamera camera;
BitmapFont font = new BitmapFont();
int[] x = new int[255];
public static boolean inPlayscreen = false;
public static String playername = "";
private boolean isConverted = false;
private Table table, table2;

public LoginScreen(CrossplatformApp game) {
    this.game = game;
    this.camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    this.stage = new Stage(new FillViewport(Constants.WIDTH, Constants.HEIGHT, camera));
    this.playTexture = new Texture("Screens/LoginScreen/LvlSelection.png");
    this.backTexture = new Texture("Screens/BackButton.png");
    this.background = new Texture("Screens/LoginScreen/loginscreen.png");
}

@Override
public void show() {

    //Give the texture of the backButton to a new ImageButton
    drawableBack = new TextureRegionDrawable(new TextureRegion(backTexture));
    backButton = new ImageButton(drawableBack);
    backButton.addListener(new ClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
            game.setScreen(new MenuScreen(game));
            MenuScreen.musicHandler.stopMusic();
        }
    });

    //Give the texture of the playButton to a new ImageButton
    drawablePlay = new TextureRegionDrawable(new TextureRegion(playTexture));
    playButton = new ImageButton(drawablePlay);
    playButton.addListener(new ClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
            game.setScreen(new LevelScreen(game));
            inPlayscreen = true;
        }
    });


    //Elements can be added here to the stage
    input.setInputProcessor(stage);

    //A table gets made with the button which leads to the level selection screen
    table = new Table();
    table.bottom();
    table.setFillParent(true);
    table.add(playButton).padBottom(40);
    stage.addActor(table);

    //A table gets made with the button which leads back to the main menu
    table2 = new Table();
    table2.bottom();
    table2.setFillParent(true);
    table2.add(backButton).padBottom(13).padRight(640);
    table2.row();
    stage.addActor((table2));
}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    if(Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed(Input.Keys.ENTER)){
        game.setScreen(new LevelScreen(game));
        inPlayscreen = true;


        if (!isConverted){
            playername = playername.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + playername.substring(1, playername.length()).toLowerCase();
            isConverted = true;
        }
    }

    game.batch.begin();

    //A possibility gets made to insert the name of the player
    game.batch.draw(background, 0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    for (int i : x) {
        if (input.isKeyJustPressed(i)){
            if (i != 62 && i != 67 && i!= 66) {
                playername += Input.Keys.toString(i).toLowerCase();
            } else if (i == 67 & playername.length() > 0){
                playername = playername.substring(0, playername.length() - 1).toLowerCase();
            } else {
                playername += " ";
            }
        }
    }

    font.draw(game.batch, playername, 0, 0);

    game.batch.end();
    stage.draw();
}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {

}

@Override
public void pause() {

}

@Override
public void resume() {

}

@Override
public void hide() {

}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    stage.dispose();

}
}
```

This is how the **''LoginScreen''** looks like:
[GameScreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/32CQD.png)

This is the error message:

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" 
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 1
at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1963)
at com.paladinzzz.game.screens.LoginScreen.render(LoginScreen.java:108)
at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.render(Game.java:46)
at com.paladinzzz.game.CrossplatformApp.render(CrossplatformApp.java:30)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:225)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:126)
```

Debugging with breakpoint:

[image]

Comment: i just quickly fly over your code so i am not 100% sure if this will be the solution but i noticed a pretty "interesting" input routine you built yourself. maybe you impelement the InputProcessor too and use its input. (ill take it later for a closer look. i am in rush at the moment edit: can you post the stacktrace for more informations about the crash?

Comment: Have just done that, maybe that clears things up. Thanks. I see that ''the string is out of range: 1'' but even if I type something and press enter it doesn't work so that's why I came with this question

Comment: add a breakpoint right before your crash and check the values in your debugger. whats your playername value?  edit: your second substring you start counting from 0 so you need length()-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The crash solution is for this line:

```
playername = playername.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + playername.substring(1, playername.length()).toLowerCase();
```

your second substring needs to use

```
playername.length()-1
```

Comment: Sorry it took so long, I was trying to fix it myself but that apparently didn't really work. It also says the ''playername'' has nothing inside of it besides ''''
I'll put a screenshot of the debugging in the post

Comment: did you implement the solution i posted here? the crash of your image happend cause you had a string with length 0 and started to pick the substring from index 1. you may also need to make sure your string is either long enough if you manipulate it, or it issnt manipulated if its too short

Comment: I made it into ''playername = playername.substring(-1, 1).toUpperCase() + playername.substring(1, playername.length()-1).toLowerCase();'' so it is able to decrease the -1 even if nothing is standing there or in other words, when it's 0 but that makes it crash as well

Comment: you cant create a substring of a negative index. imagine a string as a array(char array). you cannot access a invalid index

Comment: Okay that makes a lot of sense.. forgot about that.. but even if it I were to make it into
`playername = playername.substring(1, 2).toUpperCase() + playername.substring(2, playername.length()-1).toLowerCase();`
The value doesn't increase whatsoever

Comment: if(playername.length()>=2) {
   playername = playername.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + playername.substring(1, playername.length()-1).toLowerCase();
  } else {
   playername = "fallback name";
  }     you need to get down this basics for string manipulation(in your case of input it would be a lot better for memory to use a stringbuilder cause strings are not mutable.

Comment: I'm such an idiot.. Didn't even think about the fact that there would be an else of course.. *sigh* Sorry for troubling so much, thank you for your patients though, it indeed finally works

Comment: no worries. glad i could help. gl for your project in future